# How to fix the path of flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, path

I try to reinstall my flutter folder, I download flutter in there website and replace the old one on the folder, but when I run flutter in terminal I get this error

```
fee@Mac-mini ~ % flutter
/Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 228: 
/Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: No such file or directory
```

and I cant run even flutter doctor or flutter clean can some one help me thank you

im using mac

Comment: Please add the ```bin folder``` path to your ```environment variable```

Comment: can you help me on how to do it

Comment: thanks but it is for window Im using mac

Comment: i add this path in home environment on mac export PATH="$PATH:$HOME:/Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin"

Comment: but i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

These links will help you -

1. [Video](https://youtu.be/hL7pkX1Pfko)

Official docs - https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your path variable for flutter. At first, you need to know which shell you are using by typing `echo $SHELL` in your terminal. Depending on your shell, edit .bashrc, .bash_profile or .zshrc by any editor. Then you have to add below code to your shell:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin"
```

Then, type `source .bashrc or source .bash_profile` which you have updated earlier or logout and login back to take effect your new changes.

Check your update by typing `which flutter` or `flutter doctor` in terminal.

Comment: /bin/zsh this is the result of echo $SHELL so what will i edit base on your suggestion .bashrc, .bash_profile or .zshrc?

Comment: i add the path in .zshrc but i get the error again but i want you to know that i put the pat also in bash_profile and bashr should i remove it?

Comment: and when i echo my path this is what i get

 echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Users/fee/Documents/flutter/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

is this correct

Comment: i solve the problem by using this code 
     sudo nano /etc/paths and put the path inside

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.
Delete the cache folder under flutter/bin